# when dynamic body falls down, its `_ball.position.y` value doesn't change

Tags: scenekit

I have pretty simple question -

```
func setupScene() {
        let sceneView = view as SCNView
        sceneView.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        _scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = _scene

        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
//        Scene gravity
        sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, -70, 0)
        sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.speed = 2.0
        sceneView.delegate = self
}
```

At some point of time have spawnBall method:

```
 func spawnBall() {
        _ball = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 15))
        _ball.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "ball")
        _ball.geometry?.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIImage(named: "ball")
        _ball.geometry?.firstMaterial?.emission.intensity = 0
        _ball.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: nil)
        _ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
        _ball.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, w: 1)

        let position = SCNVector3Make(0, 15*10, -200)
        _ball.position = position
        _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(_ball)

    }
```

The question is - why when dynamic body falls down, the it's `_ball.position.y` value doesn't change?

I used to `UIKit` when you move `UIView` - it's origin changes (I was assuming to see something similar, coz I set _ball.position.y = 150 and it should go down)
And how to observe it's movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `position` of its `presentationNode` will change. The model values are left untouched by the physics engine.

Comment: Oh... what a shame...
>> Returns a node object representing the state of the node as it currently appears onscreen.<<
but it's not clear at the beginning